# How to clear form after submit in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have some simple angular 2 component with template. How to clear form and all fields after submit?. I can't reload page.
After set data with `date.setValue('')` field is stil `touched`.

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, Control} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'loading-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/loadings/loading-form.component.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class LoadingFormComponent {
    private form:ControlGroup;
    private date:Control;
    private capacity:Control;

    constructor(private _loadingsService:LoadingsService, fb:FormBuilder) {
        this.date = new Control('', Validators.required);
        this.capacity = new Control('', Validators.required);
        this.form = fb.group({
            'date': this.date,
            'capacity': this.capacity
        });
    }

    onSubmit(value:any):void {
        //send some data to backend
    }
}
```

loading-form.component.html

```ts
<div class="card card-block">
    <h3 class="card-title">Loading form</h3>

    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" [ngFormModel]="form">
        <fieldset class="form-group" [class.has-danger]="!date.valid && date.touched">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="dateInput">Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger form-control-success" id="dateInput"
                   min="0" placeholder="Enter loading date"
                   [ngFormControl]="form.controls['date']">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group" [class.has-danger]="!capacity.valid && capacity.touched">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="capacityInput">Capacity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-danger form-control-success" id="capacityInput"
                   placeholder="Enter capacity"
                   [ngFormControl]="form.controls['capacity']">
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html (section "reset the form flags")

**>=RC.6**

In RC.6 it should be supported to update the form model. Creating a new form group and assigning to `myForm`

```ts
[formGroup]="myForm"
```

will also be supported (https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11051#issuecomment-243483654)

**>=RC.5**

```ts
form.reset();
```

In the new forms module (>= RC.5) `NgForm` has a `reset()` method and also supports a forms `reset` event.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6fd5bc075d70879c487c0188f6cd5b148e72a4dd/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L179

**<=RC.3**

This will work:

```ts
onSubmit(value:any):void {
  //send some data to backend
  for(var name in form.controls) {
    (<Control>form.controls[name]).updateValue('');
    /*(<FormControl>form.controls[name]).updateValue('');*/ this should work in RC4 if `Control` is not working, working same in my case
    form.controls[name].setErrors(null);
  }
}
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6196
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6169
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4914
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6371

Comment: @masel.popowo Yes, If you want `pristine`, ..., then rebuilding the form is currently the only option.

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer how do you rebuild the form?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself yet but I guess you just drop the controlgroup and create a new one. Move the code to a function so you can call it repeatedly if necessary.

Comment: +1 for setErrors(). By the way a mistake I document here a mistake I made in case somebody else does sth similar: in case you use a placeholder e.g. 'foo' do not call control.updateValue('foo') but instead call control.setValue(null)

Comment: I don't know about a `setValue()` method on control. Only `updateValue()` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L294

Comment: This solution makes `form.value` to true which should not be the behavior of the form having empty inputs.

Comment: @essaji it's only a workaround until Angular provides something out-of-the-box. I don't know how to improve. Another workaround is to recreate the form.

Comment: you can always call .updateValueAndValidity() on each control when you submit to make sure any validation fires after youv've reset

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When taking advantage of observables, if one rebuilds the form completely, I guess all her/his `myForm.valueChanges` observable subscriptions must be recreated as well, plus the old subscriptions must be unsubscribed ... right?

Comment: You might want to have a method to which you can send your model that that be instantiated or null, and if null use empty string or value from the model. After you submit your form call this method with null parameter to rebuild the form.

Comment: From where I import Control on <=RC.3?

Comment: Don't remember. Depends on what forms module you use `@angular/forms`, `@angular/forms-deprecated`.

Comment: I'm using @angular/forms

Comment: You might be interested in this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216330/angular-5-formgroup-reset-doesnt-reset-validators

Comment: Notice that .reset() will set all fields' values to `null`, NOT the default values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588918/angular-form-reset-value-and-set-all-its-initial-value-rather-than-null. So if you're using a property (e.g. get the length of a field to show a char counter) it will throw an error. You have to map all values to `''` or rebuild the whole form.

Answer (score 41):

As of Angular2 RC5, `myFormGroup.reset()` seems to do the trick.

Comment: this works in angular 4, used it to reset the form validations

Answer (score 15):

Make a Call `clearForm();` in your .ts file

Try like below example code snippet to clear your form data.

```
clearForm() {

this.addContactForm.reset({
      'first_name': '',
      'last_name': '',
      'mobile': '',
      'address': '',
      'city': '',
      'state': '',
      'country': '',
       'zip': ''
     });
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's how I do it Angular 8:

Get a local reference of your form:

```html
<form name="myForm" #myForm="ngForm"></form>
```

```js
@ViewChild('myForm', {static: false}) myForm: NgForm;
```

And whenever you need to reset the form, call `resetForm` method:

```js
this.myForm.resetForm();
```

---

You will need `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms` for it to work. Be sure to add it to your module imports.

Comment: `@ViewChild` in Angular 8 needs 2 arguments. `@ViewChild('myForm', {static: false}) myForm: NgForm;`

Answer (score 13):

To reset your form after submitting, you can just simply invoke `this.form.reset()`. By calling `reset()` it will:

1. Mark the control and child controls as **pristine**.
2. Mark the control and child controls as **untouched**.
3. Set the value of control and child controls to **custom value** or **null**.
4. Update **value/validity/errors** of affected parties.

Please find this [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9974) for a detailed answer. FYI, this PR has already been merged to 2.0.0.

Hopefully this can be helpful and let me know if you have any other questions in regards to Angular2 Forms.

Comment: if i use reset then validations are not applied.how can i make both work ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I do it in Angular 7.3

```
// you can put this method in a module and reuse it as needed
resetForm(form: FormGroup) {

    form.reset();

    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
      form.get(key).setErrors(null) ;
    });
}
```

There was no need to call `form.clearValidators()`

Comment: That's the best (and only working for me) solution to clear form built with FormBuilder that has controls with validators.

Comment: This is the best workaround I have found so far on clearing Reactive forms. Thanks @Mauricio

Comment: I took my a while to find that method, that is the reason I shared it ;-)

Answer (score 9):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
    selector: 'example-app',
    template: '<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
        <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
        <input name="last" ngModel>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p>First name value: {{ first.value }}</p>
    <p>First name valid: {{ first.valid }}</p>
    <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>
    <p>Form valid: {{ f.valid }}</p>',
})
export class SimpleFormComp {
    onSubmit(f: NgForm) {

        // some stuff

        f.resetForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ This works fine when we have to clear all the fields. But how can we implement the same to clear only certain fields?

Answer (score 6):

To angular version 4, you can use this:

```
this.heroForm.reset();
```

But, you could need a initial value like:

```
ngOnChanges() {
 this.heroForm.reset({
  name: this.hero.name, //Or '' to empty initial value. 
  address: this.hero.addresses[0] || new Address()
 });
}
```

It is important to resolve null problem in your object reference.

reference [link](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), Search for "reset the form flags".

Answer (score 6):

this.myForm.reset();

This is all enough...You can get the desired output

Comment: Add more explanation how this line of code resolve the problem

Answer (score 3):

There is a new discussion about this (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933). So far there is only some hacks that allows to clear the form, like recreating the whole form after submitting: https://embed.plnkr.co/kMPjjJ1TWuYGVNlnQXrU/

Comment: And finally we have a method to do it in the right way: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9974

Answer (score 3):

To reset the complete form upon submission, you can use reset() in Angular. The below example is implemented in Angular 8.
Below is a Subscribe form where we are taking email as an input.

```
<form class="form" id="subscribe-form" data-response-message-animation="slide-in-left" #subscribeForm="ngForm"
(ngSubmit)="subscribe(subscribeForm.value); subscribeForm.reset()">
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="sub_email" class="form-control rounded-circle-left"
      placeholder="Enter your email" required ngModel #email="ngModel" email>
   <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-dark" type="submit" id="register"
         [disabled]="!subscribeForm.valid">Register</button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Refer official doc: https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. It's a bit hacky but its widely available in angular2 world.

Since *ngIf directive removes the form and recreates it, one can simply add an *ngIf to the form and bind it to some sort of `formSuccessfullySent`variable. => This will recreate the form and therefore reset the input control statuses.

Of course, you have to clear the model variables also. I found it convenient to have a specific model class for my form fields. This way i can reset all fields as simple as creating a new instance of this model class. :)

Comment: Addition: I'm using AngularDart, which doesn't have such a reset-method yet. Or at least I didn't discover it right now. :D

Comment: With RC.6 just re-initializing the forms model will do. If you move creating the forms model to a method, calling this method will reset the form.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Oh great! I can't wait to have this feature in Angular2 for Dart too! :) 

Because my approach as a problem: I have a list of all input elements in my form. I get these via dart-native `querySelectorAll` in `ngAfterViewInit`. I use this list to focus the next input element on keydown.enter, instead of submitting the form. This list breaks when using ngIf to reinitialize the form. :(

Comment: OK, I fixed the problem. I can re-query the InputElement instances when i reset my form model.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, now (23 Jan 2017 with angular 2.4.3) I made it work like this:

```
newHero() {
    return this.model = new Hero(42, 'APPLIED VALUE', '');
}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="heroForm.resetForm(newHero())">New Hero</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me in Angular 4

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
 registerForm: FormGroup; 

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }   

 ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      empname: [''],
      empemail: ['']
    });
 }

 onRegister(){
    //sending data to server using http request
    this.registerForm.reset()
 }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
resetForm(){
    ObjectName = {};
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, you should add an explanation stating why/how it solves the problem.

Comment: it doesn't set the 'touched', 'pristine', etc... classes back to their original values.

Comment: @Shivendra
This may work particularly for your problem but its not generic. You're making your `object` empty and not the `form`.