# Reset Form in angular 5 after submit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" (ngSubmit)="!f.form.invalid && staffDetails(model)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>


 <div class="form-group"><button [disabled]="f.invalid" *ngIf ="buttonSave" class="btn btn-info">Save</button></div>
```

after click submit button without refreshing the page when resubmit the values didn't fetch

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Yes your question not clear

Answer (score 2):

A `reset` will clear the entire form and move its state back to pristine (no validations fired), whereas a `resetForm` will just clear the values and not change the state. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39627761/6426617)

depending on what needs to be done

**html file**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
```

**ts file**

```
protected onSubmit(f: NgForm): void {

        // code here

        f.resetForm(); or f.reset();
    }
```

pass the form instance defined as `f` to the `submit` function and do the reset
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43718425/6426617)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML component**

Add #f="ngForm" in the form tag as you'have already added

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" (ngSubmit)="!f.form.invalid
    && staffDetails(model)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
   <!-- form inputs -->
 </form> <!-- form closed>
```

**Logic Component i.e TS File**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

  @ViewChild('f') myForm; //feth reference of form using ViewChild property
```

After declare, we can reset the form using reset function

```
staffDetails(data){

     this.myForm.resetForm(); //now the form is reset
}
```

Working Module for this functionality:- https://angular-xtzntk.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 1):

Use `reset()`

Try this

```
this.myform.reset();
```

Comment: but myform only using on form group i m not using that

Answer (score 1):

As you are using template driven forms try this.

Use `(ngSubmit)` event to handle the form submit event. And pass the form as a parameter to the event handler. `(ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(f)`

**In your component.html**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

**In your component.ts**

```
public onFormSubmit(ngForm: ngForm): void {
   // !f.form.invalid && staffDetails(model)
   ngForm.form.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
this.myform.reset();
```

Also, refer the [document](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#reset).

Answer (score 0):

use for to reset the form

## f.reset()

Please refer to [the link](https://angular.io/guide/forms#summary) for more details.

Comment: i used that but in resubmit the values are not submitted

Comment: Where is your re submit button. Can you please put a full code snippet what you want to achieve so that we can undersatnd your problem better

Answer (score 0):

To reset the complete form upon submission, you can use reset() in Angular. The below example is implemented in Angular 8. Below is a Subscribe form where we are taking email as an input.

```
<form class="form" id="subscribe-form" data-response-message-animation="slide-in-left" #subscribeForm="ngForm"
(ngSubmit)="subscribe(subscribeForm.value); subscribeForm.reset()">
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="sub_email" class="form-control rounded-circle-left"
      placeholder="Enter your email" required ngModel #email="ngModel" email>
   <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-dark" type="submit" id="register"
         [disabled]="!subscribeForm.valid">Register</button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

official doc: https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages

Answer (score -1):

Angular: 8.2.11 
**In Template: HTML**

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="postForm" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
```

**In Component: Typescript**

```
async onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    f.reset();
  }
```