# Angular Form reset value and set all its initial value rather than null

Tags: angular, angular-forms

For example I have a form below.

```js
searchForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl('')
  })
```

The problem is that when I use `searchForm.reset()` the initial value is set to `null` and not to empty string `''` that I set as an initial value in the `FormControl`.

I have tried doing the code below and it works.
The problem is that for example I have like 20 `FormControl`, I will need to type it all and initialize it in `.reset({firstName:'', other20properties..})`

```js
this.searchForm.reset(
      {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
      }
    );
```

Is there a way to reset the form and set all its initial value to empty string `''`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In these type of scenarios better to wrap your form initialization into a separate method and call that method after `form.reset` like this -

```
formInit() {
 searchForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl('')
 })
}


anotherFunction() {
  this.searchForm.reset();
  this.formInit();
}
```